# Using PHP to make simple HTML table showing next 90 days

Tags: php, html

How could I use PHP to make a simple 1-column HTML table with 90 rows containing the following information:

Today's date in the first row.

Tomorrow's date in the second row.

Etc.

Comment: Not clear, did you try anything ?

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by *showing the next 90 days*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a for loop up to 90, incrementing a time value by one day, and use the date function to create a date string from that value for each row:-

```
<?php

$now = time();
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   $thisDate = date("d/m/Y",$now + ($i*86400));
   echo "<tr><td>".$thisDate."</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php):

```
<table>
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

for($i = 1; $i <= 90; $i++) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<tr><td>%s</td></tr>', 
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d')
    );
}

?>
</table>
```

I've left it verbose to show what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this ([Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tL1Ri0)):

```
date_default_timezone_set('asia/dhaka'); // My timezone
$d = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(date('d-m-Y') . ' - 1 days'));
echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < 90; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . date('d-m-Y', strtotime($d . ' + '. $i .' days')) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```